# ¿Debo crear una API para una aplicación en Android?

Tags: php, android, laravel, app, programación-móvil

Lo que pasa es que estoy bastante confundido sobre cómo desarrollar una aplicación en Android con registro de usuarios, login y que se conecte a un servidor con Laravel.

Mi problema es que no sé exactamente cómo debo construir la parte del servidor para que esta mantenga una sesión, no sé si debo hacer una API RESTful con todo lo que esto implica, o si es posible utilizar los módulos (como cookies) de autenticación que tiene Laravel, o si deba usar Passport etc.

Para mi es importante que los usuarios que no hayan iniciado sesión en la app (y en el servidor) no puedan acceder a rutas de creación o eliminación de elementos.

Comment: Sin duda lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear una api rest ful del servició y luego en android con una petición HTTP y parseando json armas la solución.

Comment: Dejaré caer aquí la posibilidad de [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com). Es ideal para el tipo de aplicación que planteas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal si quieres usar Laravel en tu servidor, es efectivamente crear una API REST y usar [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport) para la autenticación.

Te dejo el [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEubh3Rmu4tn8xtkVcWnWOjQcGG4aeRK-) de una serie de videos en los que te explican cómo hacer para autenticar en Android con un backend en Laravel + Passport.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya revisé eso y en efecto es lo mejor, es que me confundía que todo lo de 0Auth2 que investigaba iba respecto a software de terceras personas, hasta que revisé los password grant tokens. Saludos.